# Is there a way to have the same tag name in ctags?

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm looking to write foos,bars,bazs by using a custom language in ctags. It works fine, I
can jump to the tag but I'm only allowed to have one unique tag name. I would
like to be able to jump through all the tags in different files with a tag named
todo1. Ctags is not generating more than one of the same tag name. If I fix this then the next question would be how to jump in vim to the same tag names? I presume `:tn` probably would not work because I've tried having the same tag names in asciidoc in the past.

For example:

[todo1]
This is something important in some/file/path/foo.txt

[todo1]
This is something important in another/path/bar.txt

[foo]
Some other foo.

My ctags config file is

```sh
--langdef=text
--langmap=text:.txt
--regex-text=/^\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]/\1/s,section/
```

In vim I do.

```
:! ctags -f ~/text/.tags -R ~/text/
:setlocal tags=~/text/.tags
```

ctags --version

```
Universal Ctags 5.9.0(b49410f), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Dec 16 2020, 11:27:14
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +iconv, +option-directory, +xpath, +packcc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tags is not generating more than one of the same tag name. If I fix this then the next question would be how to jump in vim to the same tag names?

I will try to answer the first one.

Add --fields=+n option (or --fields=+'{line}' option in Universal Ctags) to the ctags command line. That adds a `line:` field to each tag entry. The `line:` fields may make the tag entries unique.

Answer (score 0):

Ctags definitely allows having several tags with the same name, in any number of files:

```
$ cat todo.txt
[todo1] This is something important in some/file/path/foo.txt
[todo1] This is something important in another/path/bar.txt
[foo] Some other foo.

$ cat tags
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   0   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
todo1   todo.txt    /^[todo1] This is something important in     some\/file\/path\/foo.txt$/;"  s
todo1   todo.txt    /^[todo1] This is something important in another\/path\/bar.txt$/;" s
foo todo.txt    /^[foo] Some other foo.$/;" s
```

Your problem doesn't seem to be related to ctags, though, but to the way you use Vim.

- Doing `:tag foo` or pressing `<C-]>` over `foo` jumps you to the first `foo` found in the `tags` files Vim is aware of. This is where you are and you can indeed do `:tnext` to jump to the next tag.
- Doing `:3tag foo` or pressing `2<C-]>` over `foo` jumps you to the *third* `foo`.
- Doing `:tselect foo` or pressing `g]` over `foo` displays a list of `foo` tags from where you can choose.
- Doing `:tjump foo` or pressing `g<C-]` over `foo` combines the best of `:tag` and `:tselect` by acting like `:tag` when there is only one tag or like `:tselect` when there are more.

Reference:

```
:help :tag
:help ctrl-]
:help :tselect
:help g]
:help :tjump
:help g_ctrl-]
```

or `:help tags`, really.

Comment: All that does not work, at least not with the default ctags -f command. Mastake answer does work, had to add the +n. Thanks.

Comment: Well… all that has been [working perfectly](https://i.imgur.com/fB7mQey.gif) for decades, even without any config.

Comment: I did the same thing you did with another account  [here](https://imgur.com/wqGbF1E). Maybe it has something to do with asciidoc ? Who knows....

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple yet many people don't know this so I'm going to post the answer so that it can help someone out in the future.

I'm not sure if ctags allows for same name tags but it's irrelevant. What you can do is generate your own tags as explained in `:help tags-file-format`. This can be accomplished with a script containing less than 20 lines of code with a program like rip grep or you can use vimwiki plugin which implements this feature.

Here is an example of a simple tags file that jumps to bar:

```
bar exampleFile.txt 9
bar exampleFile.txt 17
```